# Adjusting output from scale_fill_distiller in stat_bin2d

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I probably have a very simple question, but I cannot figure out the answer. I am using the `diamonds` data set, and loaded the package `library(tidyverse)`. I have created a nice plot that visualizes the relation between `price` and `carat`, using `stat_bin2d`:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
stat_bin2d(bins = 50, colour = "white")
```

[image]

After some digging I found a way to adjust the colors in the plot, as I had been hoping that colors between different counts would become more distinct:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
stat_bin2d(bins = 50, colour = "white") +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Set2")
```

[image]
However, no matter which colour palette I am using, the colour distribution over the counts just does not seem to be right, as most of the bins are yellow (representing small counts). I would assume that using the counts over a log-scale would give a much better picture, as bins with lower counts would carry more weight. But I don't know how to implement this in the code. I am sure there must be a simple solution, and any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way of doing this is to use a transformation on the scale. This is quite easy, once you know how:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  stat_bin2d(bins = 50, colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Set2", trans = 'log10')
```

[image]

Things become a bit more clear (in my opinion) with a better palette:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  stat_bin2d(bins = 50, colour = "white") +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(trans = 'log10')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was easy! I also like your second plot much better. I tried to reproduce it, and got the following error message after loading the viridis package: Error: object ‘cividis’ is not exported by 'namespace:viridisLite'. But some digging solved my problem, and now it runs perfectly.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I did. But I needed to search the web to give me the answer. Thanks for your help!